# How to change state of one function component from another function component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to React Native and JavaScript. I want to update Text on click of button. I read other questions but mostly they are about class components. Here's my code below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

const Playground = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 26 }}>
        Tap count = {count}.
      </Text>
      <TapButton />
    </View>
  );
}

const TapButton = () => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Hit" />
  );
}

export default Playground;
```

Note: I know I can create Button in Playground component, But I want to know how to change state from another component or some event in another component like `onPress`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
const Playground = () => {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View style={{ padding: 5 }}>
      ...
      // send `onCountPress` as prop
      <TapButton count={count} onCountPress={setCount}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const TapButton = ({count, onCountPress}) => {
  return (
    <Button
      ...
      onPress={onCountPress(count + 1)} // update here
    />
  );
}

export default Playground;
```